# Get the rudder rotation angle of the robot's compass

Tags: python, node.js, automation, arduino, robotics

there is an electronic compass with angles of 1-360 degrees (or 0-359, whatever)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7RmH.jpg

there are variables

- **Yaw** - compass readings degrees
- **HDG** - established direction rudder degrees
- **rudder** - the degrees to turn the steering wheel (need to get)

---

**variables to check**

HDG:20
Yaw:340
=need to get rudder=40

HDG:50
Yaw:90
=need to get rudder=-40

---

What is the formula to get the angle by which to rotate?

the problem is to find the shortest turn in the right direction..

### it seems simple, but it broke my mind

something like

```html
if (Yaw<=180) {
rudder=set HDG-Yaw;
} else {
rudder=360-Yaw+setHDG;
}
```

but here is an error if setHDG is 350 and Yaw=20 ... gives 330 and it should be 30

Comment: wouldn't it be a better question for https://aviation.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: this is a simple angle formula, no aviation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (setHDG>=Yaw) 
      rudder=360-(360-setHDG+Yaw);
else 
      rudder=setHDG-Yaw;
```

Comment: this does not work :(  //// HDG:20 Yaw:340 =need to get rudder=40
///
HDG:50 Yaw:90 =need to get rudder=-40

Comment: you're right, an interesting task, but I'm confused